# SQL Select only rows where foreign key has an attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| id | Reader id | Book id | Taken date | Return date |

And, for example, 3 rows

```
id  Reader_id  Book_id  Taken_date  Return_date

1   1          1        1999-01-08  NULL

2   2          2        2015-03-09  2015-04-10

3   1          3        2013-01-01  2014-01-01
```

I need to get the id's of the readers who have returned books, so all the rows with that id in this table need to have Return_date != NULL. In the case above the query is supposed to return only the second row and not return the last row, because the reader from the last row has not returned a book. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First identify the `Reader_id` who has to return books

```
SELECT Reader_id
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  Return_date IS NULL
```

Then select the readers from which is not present in above query result

Use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  Reader_id NOT IN (SELECT Reader_id
                         FROM   yourtable
                         WHERE  Return_date IS NULL)
```

Or use `Not Exists` which can handle `NULL` values from `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   yourtable b
                   WHERE  b.Return_date IS NULL
                          AND a.Reader_id = b.Reader_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select 
      reader_id 
      from 
      tablename 
      where id not in (SELECT id
                 FROM   tablename 
                 WHERE  Return_date IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a left join :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s
ON(t.reader_id = s.reader_id
   and s.id <> t.id 
   and s.Return_date is null)
WHERE s.id is null
      AND t.Return_date is not null
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried with left outer join before, but seems like i was missing the "where" part. Appreciate your help, but I'll give the answer to MotoGP, because he was first.